# Is it a good idea to remove test devices id for AdMob when publishing an app?

Tags: android, admob

I'm preparing to launch an app in the Play Store, and after experimenting with AdMob (in test mode with my device id), I am now wondering if I should remove the test device id, and leave only the TEST_EMULATOR.

What do you think, is it necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you should remove test mode before publishing:

```
    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

In onDestroy(): `adView.destroy();`

In layout:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_publisher_id"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

In AdMob app settings select this:  **Disable test mode for all requests**

Comment: ok, thanks for the quick reply. In 2 minutes I'll be able to accept you answer :)

Comment: Wonder if anyone sees this - I've declared some test devices in my XML, is it imperative that I remove them before release? Surely it only effects the devices I listed to test on?