# AdMob on Galaxy Nexus - Android App closed itself

Tags: android, admob, galaxy, forceclose

I have programmed a simple app for testing some things.
One thing is AdMob.

On most of the Android Phone it works, but on Galaxy S3 or Galaxy Nexus, or on  Tablets not. Maybe there is a Problem with the higher resoltuion?
The problem is that the app closes immediately when it starts. I tried to integrate AdMob on XML, but that does not work with the new version really.

Here is my AdMob Code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "replaced id with this");
    //adView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutMain);
    layout.addView(adView,0);   
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And here is the LogCat

```
12-20 18:39:18.056: I/dalvikvm(541):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-20 18:39:18.066: I/dalvikvm(541):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 18:39:18.086: D/AndroidRuntime(541): Shutting down VM
12-20 18:39:18.096: W/dalvikvm(541): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.android.dertestloerk/at.android.dertestloerk.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at at.android.dertestloerk.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  ... 11 more
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  ... 23 more
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2780)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2717)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:379)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:174)
12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541):  ... 26 more
12-20 18:39:23.096: I/Process(541): Sending signal. PID: 541 SIG: 9
```

And here is my XML Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LayoutMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/hintergrund"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewLoerg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/animatedloerg"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" /> </LinearLayout>
```

Hope you can help .-)

Comment: can you post the stacktrace you are getting in logcat?

Comment: Follow this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542825/is-it-a-good-idea-to-remove-test-devices-id-for-admob-when-publishing-an-app/13542902#13542902) and also answer on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546318/admob-changing-ads/).

Comment: Ok, have deactivated the Testmode and tried it with XML, but doesnt work

Comment: @SettusBlake Post your xml code.

Comment: Have added the xml code for the Layout

Comment: You should post the answer if you've solved it rather than just making the title say "Solved".

Comment: i have .-) "Ok, solved. The background picture was a little to big. i scaled it down and now it works on High Resolution Devices "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Admob. The error is at:

18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout 12-20 18:39:18.206: E/AndroidRuntime(541): at

Ie it is crashing trying to load the XML layout, long before you programmatically ad in the Admob AdView.

Look at your layout, there is a problem there.

Comment: Ok, solved. The background picture was a little to big. i scaled it down and now it works on High Resolution Devices

Comment: But for me eventhough I scaled down the background image, its closing automatically in GAlaxy S3. I am not programatically calling add, instead calling it in XML